# R CMD Check: Unusual Checking installed package size note

Tags: r, package, cran

I'm fairly new to package development and I am about to start the process of submitting a package to CRAN.  I've been striving to get down to 0 errors, 0 warnings, & 0 notes.  There is 1 note left that I have not been able to correct (and appears as if it might be an issue with the check?).

When running the check I get the note:

```
* checking installed package size ... NOTE
  installed size is 19.0Mb
  sub-directories of 1Mb or more:
    Meta   5.0Mb
    R      3.0Mb
    help   5.0Mb
    html   2.0Mb
```

However, when I navigate to the where the package is installed, none of these printed sizes match up with what Windows Explorer shows.  The entire package folder is only 84KB, the Meta folder: 2KB, the R folder: 58KB, the help folder: 19KB, and the html folder 3KB.

I am building the package using `R version 3.3.0`.  What could be causing both the large package size and the discrepancy between `R CMD Check` and Windows?

Do imports affect the size during the check?  (`Imports: dplyr, tidyr, magrittr, stringr, SnowballC, igraph, proxy, tm`)

Comment: I was examining the installed library files in windows explorer.  I think the issue is related to R Studios "Check" button's version of the `R CMD check` under the Build tab.  Running the check with `devtools::check()` produced 0 errors, 0 warnings, & 0 notes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue appears to be related to the R Studio "Check" button's version of the `R CMD check` (located on the Build pane).  Running the check with `devtools::check()` produced 0 errors, 0 warnings, & 0 notes.  There must be some difference in how the two tools assess a package's installed size.  The package has now been successfully uploaded to CRAN.

Comment: Hi ! Note I have the same problem with eclipse when using R CMD check. Your answer was very usefull.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition: Hadley's  'R packages' book says the [following](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/check.html) about this topic:

> R CMD check is the name of the command you run from the terminal. I
> don’t recommend calling it directly. Instead, run devtools::check(),
> or press Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + E in RStudio. In contrast to R CMD check,
> devtools::check():
>
> - Ensures that the documentation is up-to-date by running devtools::document().
> - Bundles the package before checking it. This is the best practice for checking packages because it makes sure the check starts with a
>   clean slate: because a package bundle doesn’t contain any of the
>   temporary files that can accumulate in your source package, e.g.
>   artifacts like .so and .o files which accompany compiled code, you can
>   avoid the spurious warnings such files will generate.
> - Sets the NOT_CRAN environment variable to TRUE. This allows you to selectively skip tests on CRAN. (See ?testthat::skip_on_cran for
>   details.)

Judging from the comments it seems using devtools::check instead of R CMD check solved this problem also for other users.

I think the check button of R Studio calls devtools::check() already as a default.
But it could be that the default settings were changed - or the devtools package was not installed.

When you go next to the R Studio check button to '**more**' and then to '**configure build tools**' you get to the build settings. There is a checkbox called '**use devtools package functions if available**' which should be checked.